# Foreach statement in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

I can not run a loop on the arraylist of my objects in jstl. Here is the code describing the my object:

```
public class Target implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String login;
    private String title;
    private String date;
    private String description;
    private String status;

    public Target() {}
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the JSP page in which I try to print the contents of the array:

```
<%
    if (session.getAttribute("user") == null){
        response.sendRedirect("/Organaizer/");
        return;
    }
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    request.setAttribute("targets", user.getTargets());
%>
<c:forEach items="${targets}" var="current">
      <p>${current.title}</p>
      <p>${current.login}</p>
      </c:forEach>
```

Unfortunately, this implementation does not work. The data is in order, if you process the array in scriptlets, then everything works. What's my mistake?

Comment: what errors you got ?

Comment: Does user.getTargets() return a List<Target>?Also,  check that user.getTargets().size() isn't 0.

Comment: there are no errors, just there is no output of the content. The method returns an empty array

Comment: check the data then

Comment: The data is in order, if you process the array in scriptlets, then everything works

Answer (score 0):

just do it like

```
<c:forEach items="${user.targets}" var="current">
  <p>${current.title}</p>
  <p>${current.login}</p>
</c:forEach
```

get rid of the below

```
User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
request.setAttribute("targets", user.getTargets());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this decision did not help to achieve the desired result

Comment: @ОлегКорытников You still didn't mentioned what error you getting ?

Comment: there are no errors, just there is no output of the content. The method returns an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake you are doing is not importing the core tag library.

[Foreach loop iteration return blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663384/for-each-loop-with-expression-language/46663813#46663813)

Comment: Have you checked that what ${targets} is printing, before your for loop